# Получить доступ к iframe другого домена

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

Дело такое.

Хочу сделать демонстрацию своего скрипта на сайте - то бишь человек вводит url своего сайта, я его загружаю в iframe и вставляю свой скрипт для демонстрации, не более того.

Пытался сделать через запрос на свой сервер, там я обращался по url и получал ответный html (Java), ну и потом просто вставлял в iframe полученный html. Но тут столкнулся с тем что проблема с загрузкой скриптов сайта ибо могут быть скрипты у которых указано в script не полная ссылка с доменом, а просто корень `/`.

Теперь подумал о том что бы сделать iframe которому задавать `src` и вставить в него скрипт. НО!. я не могу получить доступ к iframe другого домена.

Как можно это обойти? или может есть другой вариант корректно загрузить страницу сайта?

Comment: Не получите вы доступ к iframe чужого домена. Это политика безопасности.

Answer (score 0):

В `.htacess` домена донора, который указываете в src iframe

```
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "POST, GET"
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "X-Requested-With, content-type"
```

Comment: не имею туда доступа.